# Correct MVC path mapping .NET 6 using React

Tags: reactjs, .net-core, asp.net-core-webapi

I suspect this is a very simple solution. I have created a brand new ASP.NET Core 6 project (in VS 2022) with React. The default project has a `WeatherForecast` component. I have duplicated this component and attempted to create a new controller. Unfortunately it is only returning the fallback `Index.html`.

Here is the code:

```
// React
async getSitemapData() {
        //axios.get("Sitemap")
        //    .then(resp => {
        //        console.log(resp.data);
        //        this.setState({ sitemap: resp.data, loading: false });
        //    });
        const response = await fetch('sitemap');
        const data = await response.json(); //execution does not reach this line
        console.log(data);
        this.setState({ sitemap: data, loading: false });
}
```

```
//program.cs controller mapping
app.UseStaticFiles();
app.UseRouting();

app.MapControllerRoute(
    name: "default",
    pattern: "{controller}/{action=Index}/{id?}");

app.MapFallbackToFile("index.html");
```

```
//SitemapController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Intranet.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]

    //public class DataController : ControllerBase
//Edit updated controller name
    public class SitemapController : ControllerBase
    {
        [HttpGet]
        public IActionResult Get()
        {
            try
            {
                // Read the data.json file and return its contents as JSON
                var path = Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "/App_Data/sitemap.json");
                var data = System.IO.File.ReadAllText(path);
                return new JsonResult(data);
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                return StatusCode(StatusCodes.Status500InternalServerError, ex.Message);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And for reference here is the functioning `WeatherForecastController`:

```
//WeatherForecastController.cs
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace Intranet.Controllers
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class WeatherForecastController : ControllerBase
    {
        private static readonly string[] Summaries = new[]
        {
            "Freezing", "Bracing", "Chilly", "Cool", "Mild", "Warm", "Balmy", "Hot", "Sweltering", "Scorching"
        };

        [HttpGet]
        public IEnumerable<WeatherForecast> Get()
        {
            return Enumerable.Range(1, 5).Select(index => new WeatherForecast
            {
                Date = DateTime.Now.AddDays(index),
                TemperatureC = Random.Shared.Next(-20, 55),
                Summary = Summaries[Random.Shared.Next(Summaries.Length)]
            })
            .ToArray();
        }
    }
}
```

Aside from the returned datatype (the sitemap reads a JSON file and returns the contents rather than an array. The JSON is valid as I have used it in another site which is being revamped now), everything I can see tells me it should work. Thank you.

Comment: Your URL would be /data not sitemap with the code you posted

Comment: Thank you.  I updated "Datacontroller" to "SitemapController" with same results.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to add the URL into `setupProxy.js` firstly

```
const context = [
    "/weatherforecast",

     //add here 
    "/sitemap"
];
```

Then you can use `const response = await fetch('sitemap');` to hit the `SitemapController` endpoint.

Comment: Thank you!  I knew it had to be something simple I was missing.

Answer (score 0):

Most likely, your code is not finding the JSON file you're trying read. A likely culprit `Directory.GetCurrentDirectory` which might not be what you expect at runtime.

For serving static files, the ASP.NET documentation has the following [suggestion](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/static-files?view=aspnetcore-7.0#serve-files-outside-of-web-root):

> Consider a directory hierarchy in which the static files to be served
> reside outside of the web
>
> - wwwroot
>
>   - css
>   - images
>   - js
> - MyStaticFiles
>
>   - images
>
>     - red-rose.jpg
>
> A request can access the red-rose.jpg file by configuring the Static
> File Middleware as follows:
>
> ```
> // Code omitted for brevity
>
> app.UseStaticFiles(new StaticFileOptions
> {
>     FileProvider = new PhysicalFileProvider(
>            Path.Combine(builder.Environment.ContentRootPath, "MyStaticFiles")),
>     RequestPath = "/StaticFiles"
> });
>
> // Code omitted for brevity
> ```
>
> In the preceding code, the MyStaticFiles directory hierarchy is
> exposed publicly via the StaticFiles URI segment. A request to
> https:///StaticFiles/images/red-rose.jpg serves the
> red-rose.jpg file.

Comment: Actually the execution isn't even reaching the controller, as breakpoints in debug aren't being hit.

Comment: I made a simple project to reproduce, but it works fine here. I did notice however that you included a leading `/` in the last argument to `Path.Combine`, that will make it resolve to the root of the file system. You probably want `Path.Combine(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory(), "App_Data/sitemap.json")`. (Notice the removed `/` in front of `App_Data`)

Comment: Request URL: http://localhost:44453/sitemap
Request Method: GET
Status Code: 404 Not Found
Remote Address: 127.0.0.1:44453
Referrer Policy: strict-origin-when-cross-origin

Comment: since you are using API controller, try  localhost:44453/api/sitemap

Comment: Both /api/sitemap and /sitemap (and "api/sitemap, sitemap") are returning the basic index.html page. Somewhere the api interface isn't seeing the sitemap controller.